# Python: How to modify specific (key, value) pairs at list of dicts?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, in-place

I have:

```
l = [{"a": 2}, {"a": 4}, {"a": 10}, {"a": 11}]
```

I need to multiply by 2 all "a" dict keys. So I would have:

```
l = [{'a': 4}, {'a': 8}, {'a': 20}, {'a': 22}]
```

I can do it by such code:

```
for i in l:
    i.update({"a": 2 * i["a"]})
```

But it's ugly.

There should be nice Pythonic one-liner.

Comment: What's wrong with `for i in l: i['a']*=2`?

Comment: `l.update((a, b*2) for a, b in l.items())` ?

Comment: @MarounMaroun I tried this one. `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'update'`

Comment: @viakondratiuk I didn't notice `l` is a list. Then use `l[i]` instead and run for `i`.

Comment: @ViacheslavKondratiuk  are you get any better or  faster way to update list of dict ?

Answer (score 2):

This is one liner code updating the dictionaries and returning the list. However, if dictionaries do not have `a` key it raises `KeyError`. And, all the dictionaries are updated until an exception occurs. I hope it helps but code readibility matters so simply updating dictionary in for loop does not cost much.

```
>>> l = [{"a": 2}, {"a": 4}, {"a": 10}, {"a": 11}]
>>> map(lambda x:(x,x.__setitem__("a",x["a"]*2))[0],l)
[{'a': 4}, {'a': 8}, {'a': 20}, {'a': 22}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [{k:v*2} for d in l for k, v in d.items()]
```

Comment: It won't work if I will have dict with keys different from `"a"`

Comment: @viakondratiuk- It doesn't matter if you have different keys

Answer (score 0):

This also takes into account if there actually is a key `a`.

```
for d in l:
  if 'a' in d:
    d['a'] *= 2
```

Or

```
for d in l:
  try:
    d['a'] *= 2
  except KeyError:
    # No key `a`
    pass
```

Comment: Doesn't iterating a list like that cause `d` to be a copy and thus modifying it would have no effect on the original list?

Comment: No you get the actual dictionary that is in the list. There is no implicit copy here.